# How to determine memory usage in my .NET application

Tags: .net, memory-management

I have a website where some user can upload his dll. I need to create an instance from this dll and call a specific method. Moreover, I need to do it with several dll's in 1 process, so it is not an option for me to use System.Diagnostics.Process.

Is there a way to determine how much memory does this method call use or limit it in my application runtime?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: BTW, if one of us answered your question, can you please accept the answer by clicking the tick next to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Memory usage in .Net is very difficult to gauge - It will depend on a lot of factors like whether garbage collection run, how much of the framework has been loaded, etc.

You can look at memory usage on a per-process level using [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Assuming for a moment you've already considered the security implications of running a users code in a semi-trusted environment, you need to use an [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to load the DLL - That way it can be unloaded without restarting the whole website / worker pool

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer.
I will try to explain more precisely what do I need. :)
My project is a game for developers, where they need to upload their code and "fight" against each other.
So after there are some uploaded dlls, we can create a round to determine who wins :).
I thought about creating this round in a separate process, and in this process I was going to create instances and call methods from uploaded dlls. And I need to limit memory usage for this instances, so if developer runs out of this limit - he loses the round.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Seperate process is definitely required - You might even consider a process-per-dll depending on how many you're expecting to host at once - That way you can still monitor memory usage using performance counters.

Comment: Another option would be to expose a "heap" ala `Byte()` or something a little more clever (`Dictionary`?) to your developers which they have to use for all variables - you can then control the `Byte()` explicitly and use reflection to make sure they're not allocating memory inside their assemblies.

Comment: Oh, how could not I find this solution earlier by myself :) Thanks a lot.
But I will try to work with performance counters first. It is a new interesting thing for me :)

Comment: Glad I could help :) Welcome to SO - Hopefully we'll see you more in the future

Comment: NB: I've updated the link to performance counter to point a the .Net 4 Framework (The old link was the 1.1 framework)

Comment: One last thought, you'll need to learn about garbage collection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx

Answer (score 5):

If you use .NET 4.0 have a look at [MemoryFailPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145965.aspx).

Another suggestion: .NET 4.0 now offers facilities to supervise the memory consumption of an AppDomain ([AppDomain.MonitoringIsEnabled Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.monitoringisenabled.aspx)). You can for instance use the main AppDomain to poll and tear down an AppDomain, if it uses too much memory.

Answer (score 4):

Could you use GC.GetTotalMemory as an alternative to track your memory usage?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Seriously you cannot go past [Red Gates Ants Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) - free 14 day trial...